# Differences in webrequests between c# and java

Tags: java, c#, webrequest

I'm sending a request to a page in C# and Java but i'm getting a different results.

My code in C#:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=123");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
response.Close();
```

My code in Java:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try {
    //Create connection
    URL url = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/results");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    String urlParameters = "search_query=123";
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
        Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

    //  Send request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
        connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.close();

    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if not Java 5+

    String line;
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close();
    m_htmlDoc = response.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    m_htmlDoc =  null;
} finally {
    if(connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect(); 
    }
}
```

In C# the response is correct, I'm getting the same HTML as the web
but in Java I'm getting [this HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7PrB.png).

Why there are differences, and how can it be fixed?

**Update**:
this is the code of java after modification:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=123");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            m_htmlDoc = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            m_htmlDoc =  null;
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect(); 
            }
        }
```

but still the response is different

Comment: You're using GET in C# but POST in Java. Why use a different method if you're trying to do the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i've added an update above but still the difference is there

Comment: I think i got it to work, what i've missed is the use of user agent set to mozilla/5.0 what is this user agent? what it's rule? another thing, when i put the cursor in the html string i'm not getting all the string ( there's a 3 dots in the end). how can i get the full string? thank you for your help

Comment: The user agent string is something that could be used by the server to (unreliably) try to detect the type of client (browser, other program, etc). Maybe they're trying to block exactly what you're trying to do, since they have a separate API that's made for computer consumption? As for the dots I presume that by "put the cursor in the html string" you meant that you looked at the variable using a debugger. That's probably the debugger just truncating a long string. Print it to the screen or something to look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.